# JSONP not working in AngularJS as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

The first commented $scope.url which I took from angular documentation works fine, similarly I am trying to invoke another public url which gives me back the response but always goes to error callback.

Both the URLs are in public domain, so please feel free to try.

```
                $scope.method = 'JSONP';
             // URL 1: Working
             // $scope.url = 'https://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&name=Super%20Hero';

             // URL 2: Not working (Getting response with status 200OK but going to error callback)           
                $scope.url= 'http://apps.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/services/mpconnect_service.cfm?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&mainSearchCriteria.v.cs=2.16.840.1.113883.6.96&mainSearchCriteria.v.c=41381004&knowledgeResponseType=application/javascript';

                $scope.fetch = function() {
                    $scope.code = null;
                    $scope.response = null;

                    $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache: $templateCache}).
                        success(function(data, status) {
                             console.log(data);
                             console.log(status);
                        }).
                        error(function(data, status) {
                            console.log(data);
                            console.log(status);
                        });
                };
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason **dots** are stripping from callbacke method name http://apps.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/services/mpconnect_service.cfm?callback=angular.callbacks._0&mainSearchCriteria.v.cs=2.16.840.1.113883.6.96&mainSearchCriteria.v.c=41381004&knowledgeResponseType=application/javascript

This response can’t be handle by **AngularJS** as Angular wants to call angular.callbacks.0

### Some development background

```
var jsonpDone = jsonpReq(url.replace('JSON_CALLBACK', 'angular.callbacks.' + callbackId),
    function() {
        if (callbacks[callbackId].data) {
            completeRequest(callback, 200, callbacks[callbackId].data);
        } else {
            completeRequest(callback, status || -2);
        }
        callbacks[callbackId] = angular.noop;
});
```

Every URL that has `JSON_CALLBACK` string inside will be replaced by `angular.callbacks.{\D}`

source: AngularJS.js

Comment: Thanks @Krzysztof for confirming the response is not suitable for Angular. The Web Service is not under my control, I will find another way to call it than using Angular.

Comment: I’ve found one ugly solution. You can external api with callback other than `JSON_CALLBACK`. And (this is ugly part) you must create global method with the same name as callback. In that global method you can handle response.